# Regex to find where space is missing between number and word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using regex to clean some text files.
In some places, spaces are missing as in the second line below:

```
1.9 Beef Curry
1.10Banana Pie
1.11 Corn Gravy
```

I need an expression to find a zero-length match at the position between 0 and B, so that I can replace it (in Notepad++) with a space. Note that numerators can be one or two digits, and there can also be one (i.e. 1. Exotic Disches) or three levels (i.e. 2.5.1 Chicken).

Can someone please give the answer?

I would have thought one of the following should work, but Notepad++ calls it invalid. Would also appreciate it if someone can tell my why...

```
(?<=\.\d\d|\.\d)(?! )(?!\.)
(?<=\.\d{1,3)(?! )(?!\.)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's working, but it also catches `4` in `4. Other Stuff`, which I don't want. I'll modify my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of

```
^\d[\d.]*+(?!\h)
^\d[\d.]*+(?! )
^(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)(?!\h)
```

Replace with `$&` .

Settings and test:

[image]

**Details**

- `^\d[\d.]*+(?!\h)` matches a digit and then  0 or more digits/dots and once they are all matched, a horizontal whitespace is checked for. If there is no whitespace, there is a match.
- `^\d[\d.]*+(?! )` is the same, just the check is performed for a regular space.
- `^(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)(?!\h)`  is more specific, it matches

  - `^` - start of line
  - `(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)` - an atomic group preventing backtracking:
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0 or more sequences of `.` and 1+ digits
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
  - `(?!\h)` - no horizontal whitespace allowed immediately on the right

Comment: I tried `^\d[\d.]*+(?!\h)` and indeed it matches the numbers just before I need the space, and then if I use the replace string like you said - it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is enough, just to look for the zero length spaces `\B` (non [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) between [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and check, if preceded by a digit and not followed by a digit. If so, replace with space.

```
\B(?<=\d)(?!\d)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9FGs70/2)

- at any `\B` *non word boundary*
- `(?<=\d)` [looks](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) behind for a digt
- `(?!\d)` looks ahead for no digit

For further restricting the digit part to *dot, followed by 1-3 digits*, try something like [`\.\d{1,3}\B\K(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/9FGs70/4) where [`\K` resets](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match. Or [without `\K` and replace by `$0`](https://regex101.com/r/9FGs70/5)

Just to mention: Also the underscore belongs to word characters. If your input contains underscores, e.g. something like `1_` and you don't want to add space here, change the lookahead to `(?![\d_])`

Answer (score 0):

My alternative attempt also working
Find what: `^(\d\.\d+) ?(?=\w)`
Replace with: `$1`    a `space`  after `$1`