# R: gsub() returns regex pattern symbols instead of the value matching the pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to parse a few thousand street addresses that are lacking spaces. I can do most of this with the `postmastr` package, but I need to insert a space between the street number and the first letter of the street name.

I have found a pattern that I like that searches the strings well (inspired by the 3rd response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371655/regex-to-find-where-space-is-missing-between-number-and-word)), but when I try to use gsub to add in a space, I either get just a space or the actual regex code instead of the matched value plus a space.

For example, I have an address like `123MAINST` and I would like it to be `123 MAINST`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
x <- "123MAINST"
gsub("^(?>\\d+(?:\\d+)*)(?!\\h)(?=\\w{3,})", "\\1 ", x, perl = TRUE)
```

gives me

```
[1] " MAINST"
```

```
gsub("^(?>\\d+(?:\\d+)*)(?!\\h)(?=\\w{3,})", "$1 ", x, perl = TRUE)
```

gives me

```
[1] "$1 MAINST"
```

and

```
gsub("^(?>\\d+(?:\\d+)*)(?!\\h)(?=\\w{3,})", "^(?>\\d+(?:\\d+)*)\\h(?=\\w{3,})", x, perl = TRUE)
```

gives me

```
[1] "^(?>d+(?:d+)*)h(?=w{3,})MAINST"
```

What am I doing wrong? I've look over the `gsub()` documentation and many articles and stack overflow questions and I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: I feel it might be helpful to give more (complex) examples (maybe 10) from your real data set.

Comment: You confused an atomic group with a capturing group, and since there is no capturing group, `\1` is an empty string. All you need is to replace `(?>\\d+(?:\\d+)*)` with `(\\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

Per the suggestion of @Wiktor, I just needed a capturing group, so I used `gsub("^(\\d+)(?!\\h)(?=\\w{3,})", "\\1 ", x, perl = TRUE)` which worked great.

For reference:

```
x <- "123MAINST"
gsub("^(\\d+)(?!\\h)(?=\\w{3,})", "\\1 ", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "123 MAINST"
```